# C# рефлексия. Получение значения приватного поля экземпляра класса?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Есть экземпляр класса `Class1`, каким образом можно получить его `aValue` поле?
Вопрос крайне глупый, понимаю... и все же. Получается получить только статические поля, а для экземпляров как быть?

```
public class Class1{

    private int aValue;
    public Class1(int a){
        this.aValue = a;
    }
}

Class1 cls = new Class1(10);
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как он задан на английском, а не русском языке

Comment: Даже не заметил что это ру домен. перевел, раз так нужно)

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/304520/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно указать маску:

```
Class1 cls = new Class1(10);   
FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(Class1).GetField("aValue", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
int a = (int)fieldInfo.GetValue(cls);
```

Comment: чутка наоборот делал оказалось... getValue Null передавал а не экземпляр. то что нужно.

Answer (score -1):

Один из принципов ООП - Инкапсуляция, означает что доступ к "некоторым" свойствам класса возможен только "внутри капсулы" из метода класса;
Напиши метод `public int GetValue() {return aValue}`

Comment: Полного доступа к классу у меня нету, ибо пишу некоторую модификацию...  иначе не было бы и нужды в рефлексии...